# UIView.animate on frame when within a UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to build a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` delegate which moves the width/height of a `UIView` when it hits a certain x value but I'm running into this weird flicker that occurs when the value passes the threshold (65px in the example below).

```
@objc func moveCardRec(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    if sender.translation(in: self).x < -65.0 {
       self.makeButtonPop()
    } else {
       self.makeButtonUnPop()
    }
}
```

It's like the view that I'm moving the x value with the pan gesture is moving for a second when the `UIView` (the one I want to pop/animate for sec) is lagging behind or resetting a frame. No clue.

Attaching a gif of what's happening now. You'll see that for a split second it jitters. The `makeButtonPop()` function is just a `UIView.animate` on the frame of the circle image view with the check mark in it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm stupid. Spent hours on this.

Found how to fix it. Make sure the `UIView` you want to animate is within a contained `UIView` (like a parent). So the above example, the purple circle is within a `UIView` which doesn't change sizes.

The child within the parent changes sizes. For some reasons when the animated `UIView` and the one I'm dragging are in the same container / same direct parent, they don't like each other and flicker.

Hope this helps someone else!